# How do I prevent the program, "magnus," from popping up upon every login?

Tags: kde, startup-applications, accessibility

I am running Ubuntu Studio 21.10 on Kernel Version 5.13.0-2-lowlatency (64-bit);KDE Plasma & Frameworks versions are 5.22.5 and 5.86.0, respectively. Qt is version 5.15.2.

The system is AMD w/ 8 GB RAM.

I don't recall doing anything to tell **magnus** to pop up and annoy me each time I log in.

*It is not in the usual "Startup" system setting dialog.*

I'm unaware of other "startup" settings where it may be hiding.Do you know where/what I need to modify to prevent this tool from popping up without being requested.

Comment: Does uninstalling the program ok?

Comment: A stock install of Magnus (screen magnifier) will autostart. The reason is not documented, but one imagines it's to avoid the chicken-and-egg problem of a visually-impaired user unable to see how to launch it. Run `dpkg -L magnus` to see where all the Magnus files are located. Find the location of the file `magnus-autostart.desktop`. Edit that desktop file to disable autostart.

Comment: @user535733: Can you promote your comment to an answer? Also, the fact that the user isn't provided with clear instructions about what magnus is, why it autostarts, or how to disable it, is, IMO, a bug.

Comment: @MRule I would gently suggest that it's *design decision*, perhaps one that you feel introduces a usability papercut. In this case, only Ubuntu Budgie and Ubuntu MATE are affected. Both are community-driven flavors of Ubuntu -- you can get involved and solve that papercut.

Comment: I'm not saying that Magnus shouldn't be there. I'm saying that introducing a new, unexplained autostart program --- with absolutely no information about what it is, why it autostrats, or how to turn it off, is a bug in the documentation and/or on-screen information accessible via magnus on first encounter.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: Deleting a file that is part of a package is not considered a best practice.

Straight up removing the file solved the issue.

> sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/magnus-autostart.desktop

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Hidden=true` as the last line of `/etc/xdg/autostart/magnus-autostart.desktop` will prevent magnus autostart for all users.

Copying that file to `~/.config/autostart` and adding the `Hidden=true` there instead will disable autostart for individual users without requiring root privileges.

Removing `/etc/xdg/autostart/magnus-autostart.desktop` as suggested in another answer works but deleting a file that is part of a package is not considered a best practice.